# On extracting primes from coprimes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Proof or disprove the following statement -

There exists infinitely many  $a$ and $b$ which are pair of co-prime integers , either $ab+1$ or $ab-1$ is prime.

**Motivation**- Looking at some twin prime pairs and calculating a lot - I guessed something like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any odd prime number $p$. Let $a$ be the greatest power of $2$ which divides $p-1$, and $b=\cfrac {p-1}a$ then $ab+1=p$ and $(a,b)=1$.

You can do the same for $ab-1$ by taking factors of $p+1$.

Since $p$ was arbitrary, and there are infinitely many primes, there are infinitely many pairs $(a,b)$ satisfying your criterion.

Comment: Note that if you avoid the occasional cases where $ab+1$ or $ab-1$ are powers of $2$, you can get as many non-trivial factorisations as you like (both factors greater than $1$). With a little more work you can do the same with primes other than $2$ - for example if $p=6r-1$ then $p+1$ has a factor $3$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is trivial from the infinitude of primes. If $p$ is prime, let $a=p+1$ and $b=1$, then $ab-1$ is prime.

Comment: ofcourse we don't count the trivial case